# Heroku can't detect my forms.py. "ModuleNotFoundError at /"

Tags: django, forms, heroku

I keep getting a "ModuleNotFoundError at /" error when I try to visit my Heroku app. It works fine when I run it on `localhost:8000`.

My project directory looks like this:

frontpage

-**pycache** (folder)

-migrations (folder)

-templates (folder)

-__init.py__

-admin.py

-apps.py

-forms.py

-models.py

-tests.py

-urls.py

-views.py

Log error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'frontpage.forms'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://cottonthebutton.herokuapp.com/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'frontpage.forms'
Exception Location: /app/frontpage/views.py in <module>, line 5
Python Executable:  /app/.heroku/python/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/app/.heroku/python/bin',
 '/app',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python38.zip',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 1 Aug 2020 19:16:39 +0800
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://cottonthebutton.herokuapp.com/

Django Version: 3.0.8
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'frontpage']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 544, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/PersonalWebsite/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('frontpage.urls'))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/frontpage/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from frontpage import views
  File "/app/frontpage/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from frontpage.forms import MessageForm

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'frontpage.forms'
```

Comment: Try using 'frontpage.apps.FrontpageConfig' or whichever configuration file you have instead of frontpage?

Comment: What configuration file? `frontpage` (the one on the very top) is the name of the folder. I think it's the project folder because the manage.py file is under that.

Comment: Do you have an `apps.py` file inside your frontpage application?

Comment: Oh my god. I am very sorry. I forgot to add `forms.py` in my git push. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to include `forms.py` in my git push. Sorry!!!